# When use async_write_some and async_write

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I was reading the documentation of Boost Asio and it says that

> `boost::asio::async_write_some` may NOT transfer all of the data to the peer. Consider using the `async_write` function if you need to ensure that all data is written before the asynchronous operation completes.

So here is my question, in which cases should we use them, isn`t VERY important to ensure that all the data is written?! when to use async_write_some just this function seems to me useless?

Comment: `write_some` is basically how the network works, underlying socket implementations decide packet divisions and the caller always needs to check. This is indeed why Boost Asio adds the more high-level function `async_write`: the question is not why the low-level function exists. It's why the high-level exists, and you explained that yourself

Answer (score 4):

`async_write` is useful in request-reply mode when you need to send a specific response that fully fits in your buffer. I.e. when you switch to reading mode after the message is sent.

But if you need to send more data than you have in your write buffer then it doesn't matter if the whole buffer is sent or not, because you still have more data to send. In that case ensuring that the whole buffer is sent is going to be inefficient because the last chunk may be smaller than it could have been if you just called `async_write_some` in a loop, filling up the buffer with more data as you go. For optimal performance you want to ensure there is always enough data in the send buffer to fill a full frame.

Comment: "that fully fits in your buffer" - or a sequence of buffers

Answer (score 1):

When you are asynchronously reading from one place, and writing to another, you probably just want to shove some bytes to the destination, and want to know when there is room in the buffer to send some more.  You only need to use `async_write` for the last write (when you know there is no more to send)